# Working with shader code

Tags: opengl

I am starting my first project in OpenGL/GLSL and I was wondering, how do you work with code of shaders?

Because it needs to be const char and syntax higlighting shows everything in the same color (as string) and so its difficult to navigate in code.

```
const char *shader = ..."void main()\n"...;
```

Do you edit the code and then add quotation marks or do you just write it with quotation marks from the start? Thanks

edit: using VS2012

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about editing source code/using software tools, but is too old to migrate to Stack Overflow.

Comment: This question felt more like a part of development methodology so I posted it here. Anyway, feel free to close it - I have my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do to make including shader code in C(++) source files more convenient is defining a macro like this:

```
#define GLSL(x) "#version #150\n" #x
```

Example:

```
const char* shader = GLSL(
    out vec4 outColor;
    void main() {
        outColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
);
```

This will give you better formatting and basic C-style syntax highlighting:

[image]

Note that new lines will be ignored, so any preprocessor statements must be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

some use separate files and include them as resources, some use macros, some use external files and read them in at runtime.

both of the external file options will allow syntax highlighting

and technically you don't need `const char*`, just a `char*` will do (it is implicitly convertible)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the newly released [ShaderFrog](http://shaderfrog.com) to work with GLSL shaders directly in the browser, with full syntax highlighting and debugging information. I am the author of this tool, and created it for an accessible way to edit GLSL shaders for use in OpenGL applications.

Comment: +1. Despite being an ad, it's very ontopic and the site by the link is very cool.